# adding multiple textbox .net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

What i want is when i input a number in texbox1.text like for example i enter 3 it should show 3 textbox but i always get an error. and also i have to save it in database but i dont know how. Help Please..

```
Private boxes(TextBox1.text) As TextBox


Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim newbox As TextBox
    For i As Integer = 1 To TextBox1.Text
        newbox = New TextBox
        newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(575, 35)
        newbox.Location = New Point(10, 10 + 35 * (i - 1))
        newbox.Name = "TextBox" & i
        newbox.Text = newbox.Name
        'connect it to a handler, save a reference to the array and add it to the form controls
        AddHandler newbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
        boxes(i) = newbox
        Me.Controls.Add(newbox)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Comment: So what error do you get and on which line?

Comment: Im getting the error in Private boxes (Textbox1.text) As Textbox and also for i as integer = 1 to textbox1.text                                                                                          Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Heh. For some reason I didn't see the first line of code. See my answer for corrections anyway.

Comment: It didnt work for me it should be that when i enter a number in textbox like when i enter 3 it would show 3 textbox but it doesnt show . how can i call it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. The error I get when I try to run your code is :-

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`
```

This is because you're trying to start a loop using a string as the termination index for the loop. Try using

```
For i As Integer = 1 To Val(TextBox1.Text)
```

your next problem will depend on how you've declared `boxes`. If you have declared it like this ..

```
Dim boxes() As TextBox
```

You'll end up with a Null reference exception because when you declared `boxes`, you didnt supply any elements. To remedy this you'll need to add this just before your loop ..

```
ReDim Preserve boxes(Val(TextBox1.Text))
```

If `boxes` is a list.. and to be honest .. thats a better choice than an array, instead of the above line you'll need to change

```
boxes(i) = newbox
```

to

```
boxes.Add(newbox)
```

You might also need to change other code associated with `boxes`, but the work will be worth it.

Your biggest problem is that you're trying to get a value from a `TextBox` that hasn't even appeared yet. You've put your code inside the form's `load` event. It really needs to be in a separate method. Oh and rather than use the `TextBox.changed` event you should use a button control to execute the method. Otherwise it's too easy for someone to change the number in the textbox. With your code, each time the textbox is changed (deleting a digit or adding another digit), more TextBoxes will be added and you could end up with lots of them.

So possible final code should look like ..

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim boxes As New List(Of TextBox)

    Private Sub Addbuttons(buttonCount As Integer)
        Dim newbox As TextBox
        For i As Integer = 1 To buttonCount
            newbox = New TextBox
            newbox.Size = New Drawing.Size(575, 35)
            newbox.Location = New Drawing.Point(10, 10 + 35 * (i - 1))
            newbox.Name = "TextBox" & i
            newbox.Text = newbox.Name
            'connect it to a handler, save a reference to the array and add it to the form controls
            boxes.Add(newbox)
            Me.Controls.Add(newbox)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Addbuttons(Val(TextBox1.Text))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It didnt work for me it should be that when i enter a number in textbox like when i enter 3 it would show 3 textbox but it doesnt show . how can i call it thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry perhaps I should have explained by last paragraph more. You've put the code into the form's load event. It should be in a separate sub - I'll edit the answer to show it shortly. Give me a moment to edit and add more text.

Comment: Sure. Though really it should be asked as a separate post - especially if it might be useful to other users

Comment: Oh and (being cheeky here) Dont forget to click the tick to the left of the answer so that other users can see that it's an answer that works for you - and (cough) I get a bit of reputation as well ;-)

Comment: So what's your next question :)

Comment: If code1.Text <> "" Or Not code1.Items.Contains(code1.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Please select a Code Department from the list", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Code Department not available")
            code1.Focus()
            Exit Sub        This is my code for limiting the combobox but because of this i cant have a null combobox

Comment: so you want to be able to make sure  the combo box isnt empty before you run that code?

Comment: No. the combobox can should be save even if it dont have value but because of that restriction it wont save when it is null

Comment: So you want to save the combobox to a file? And if it is null, it wont save. Is that it?

Comment: oh can i rather ask. how can i insert it in database/ the new boxes?

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately I dont know enough about databases - I should, but I have never learned about them . You would be best to ask a new question so smarter people than me can answer for you. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. OK It's 01:33 here. Time to sleep. Goodnight :)